# Get-Service causing unexpected formatting

Tags: powershell

I am working on a simple script whilst trying to learn Powershell. I am basically just taking information about the machine and displaying it back with some formatting. When I use the Get-Service to show information about only stopped services, it works fine, but then I attempt to show information about network adapters and this is where my problem starts.

The output shows Windows Services and then Available Interfaces before the information about the network adapters when it should show Windows Services followed by the information about the stopped services, THEN say "Available Interfaces" followed by the network info. Why is this executing the write-host "Available Interfaces" before the output is being shown when it is on the line before? Thanks for any help!

```
Write-Host "Windows Services"
Write-Host "*********"
Get-Service | Select-Object -Property Status,Name,DisplayName | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped"}
Write-Host "Available Interfaces"
Write-Host "*******************"
Get-NetAdapter -Name "*" | Format-List -Property "*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) writes the output directly to console, while `Get-Service` and `Get-NetAdapter` are sent to the pipeline where they may take time to execute and return the output to console. If you want to synchronize the output you can use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) instead.